# How enable physical keyboard on Emulator in Android Studio or visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, android-studio, keyboard, emulation, android-virtual-device

I can't write Persian language with physical keyboard on Android Studio or Visual Studio 2019 emulators.

What i did:
(Pixel Pie 9.0 - API 28)

- Enabled hw.keyboard config and checked "hw.keyboard=yes" in config.ini in AVD in Visual Studio
- After Android emulator startup in Setting> System> Languages & inputs> physical keyboard> qwerty2> set up keyboardlayout> enabled Persian.

But when i go to SMS and write with my physical keyboard, it just write English not Persian.

If someone can help me, I would be really appreciate.

Comment: @saeed-neamati would you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible solutions to change the device language.

1. Open menu -> Setting -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Locale. Set any locale from this. It depends on android os version and on device manufacturer.
2. Emulator contains app called "Custom Locale". using that app also you can change the locale of your emulator. I didn't check all type of emulator running on different types of CPU and android version so its not gerrently that this app is present in the emulator.

Or you can code this,

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
```

Please let me know this sorted or not?

Comment: thanks for your answer. i do not want to change device language, i just want to write with my physical keyboard in android emulator with persian language keyboard

Answer (score 0):

When the keyboard opened, click on the setting icon.You will get languages option.On clicking that you can choose your language.

[image]